# Change selected value in Javascript - Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, combobox

I have a combo-box in view of RoR (Ruby 1.9) application like this:

```
<%= collection_select(:source, :source_id, @objects, :id, :name, :selected =>1)
```

I want to change the selected value in javascript. Does it possible? If yes, please show me a sample code about this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the selected option of a select box with something like this:

```
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('select[name="test"]')[0]; // Change this to target your select box
sel.selectedIndex = 1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/ffwXb/

Comment: That's great! My problem is solved by following your solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use JQuery its very easy

```
<%= collection_select(:source, :source_id, @objects, :id, :name, html_options = {selected: 1, id: 'yourid'})
```

In .js

```
$("#yourid").val('thevalueyouwantselected');
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I want to do it inside <script> </script> tag. I tried your suggestion, but I not work in my case! Maybe It'll work if I use .js file. I'll try later. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion.